# Get-ADGroup - Group Name, ManagedBy Name and Email

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to get the the Group Name, Managed By Name and Managed by Email in a PowerShell query similar to this.

```
Get-ADGroup -filter {Name -like "*Admins" }
```

The output would look something similar to:

```
Group Name | Managed By Name | Managed By Email
```

The issue I'm having is with joining `Get-ADGroup` and `Get-ADUser`.  In SQL this "join" would happen on `get-adgroup.managedby = get-aduser.distinguishedname`.  I know that's not how it works in Powershell, just thought I'd throw out an example of what I'm trying to do.

Any help would both be welcomed and appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see @Mathias R. Jessen beat me to it, but here's what I had:

```
Get-ADGroup -filter {Name -like "*IT*" } -Properties managedBy |
ForEach-Object { 
$managedBy = $_.managedBy;

if ($managedBy -ne $null)
{
 $manager = (get-aduser -Identity $managedBy -Properties emailAddress);
 $managerName = $manager.Name;
 $managerEmail = $manager.emailAddress;
}
else
{
 $managerName = 'N/A';
 $managerEmail = 'N/A';
}

Write-Output $_; } |
Select-Object @{n='Group Name';e={$_.Name}}, @{n='Managed By Name';e={$managerName}}, @{n='Managed By Email';e={$managerEmail}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @dugas,  it appears the very first email address propagates down through the results.

Comment: @Rob - Had a typo. I also updated to check for null managed by.

Comment: I was able to tweak the query to fit my needs.  Thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter { Name -like "*Admins" } -Properties managedBy,mail
$Groups |Select-Object Name,@{Name='ManagedBy';Expression={(Get-ADUser $_.managedBy).Name}},Mail
```

The `@{}` syntax after `Select-Object` is known as a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx).

---

You could also pipe the groups to `ForEach-Object` and call `Get-ADUser` inside the process scriptblock:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like "*Admins"} -Properties managedBy,mail |ForEach-Object {
    # Find the managedBy user
    $GroupManager = Get-ADUser -Identity $_.managedBy

    # Create a new custom object based on the group properties + managedby user
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        Name       = $_.Name
        ManagedBy  = $GroupManager.Name
        Email      = $_.mail
    }
}
```

Comment: Note this will get the group's mail address, whereas I thought the OP wanted the group manager's mail address.

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen - The email address being pulled is the email for the group, not for the Managed By user.

Answer (score 0):

I would something do like this:

```
# Get all groups into a variable
$Group = Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like "*Admin*"} | Select-Object -expandProperty Name
  foreach ($Groups in $Group){
  # Get ManagedBy name for each group (If ManagedBy is empty group wil not be listed)
    $User = Get-ADGroup $Groups -Properties * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ManagedBy
    foreach ($Users in $User){
       # Get Name and EmailAddress for each User
       $Name = Get-ADUser $Users | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
       $Email = Get-ADUser $Users -Properties * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty EmailAddress
    # Write output
    Write-Host $Groups "," $Name "," $Email 
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't do `-Properties *` it pulls all properties of the object. That is a lot of useless data. Just pull what you want and not use `*`. Your do multiple queries when you don't need to.